# How many different Product has one Market SQL

Tags: sql

I try to get an output where there are the Market_id and the number of different Product_id of the market

Table1

```
| Market_id | Product_id |

| 01        | 105        |

| 01        | 12         |

| 01        | 105        |

| 02        | 34        |

| 02        | 34         |

| 03        | 22         |

| 03        | 22         |

| 03        | 22         |

| 03        | 18         |
```

output like this

```
|01   | 2 |

|02   | 1 |

|03   |2  |
```

and for example if i have a market_id has not Product_id how can i return 
| 05 | 0 |
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  Being spoon fed the answer on this site probably won't result in you learning very much SQL.  You should try to solve this problem yourself first.

Comment: Hint : `GROUP BY` & `COUNT(DISTINCT Product_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Solution:

```
 select market_id,count(distinct product_id) as count from TableName group by market_id
```